# PHP Strip numbers

Tags: php, regex, yii

Hello I need to put dot between first number and second number my result is:

`11` I need to make him like this `1.1` how ?

```
if ( strlen($model->rate) == 2 )
{

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$model->rate = $model->rate[0] . '.' . $model->rate[1];
```

**Also**, your if condition should look like the following (note [the number of equal signs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)):

```
if ( strlen($model->rate) == 2 )
```

Comment: thx man but i have PHP notice "Uninitialized string offset: 1" i think coz I using Yii framework

Comment: @abudayah:  Nope, that would be a result of the string not being at least 2 characters long.  Make sure you are using the new `if` condition I included in my answer.

Comment: @abudayah  You should change `$model->rate` to `$model->imdb_rate`.

Comment: @abudayah too late! Now that I know the secret of IMDB I shall rule the world!!! Mwhahaha!